# Непонятные отступы в safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, scss, safari

Верстаю сайт, возникла проблема, при просмотре страницы на любом устройстве кроме айфона, а точнее его браузера Safari, у меня всё выглядит отлично, никаких проблем, как на фото 1. Но на айфоне, вид у блока с ссылками на соц. сети неко меняется: они слазят вниз, как на фото 2. Для отступа я пишу:

```
position: absolute;
top: 73vh;
```

И везде это работает нормально, во всех браузерах на телефоне, кроме айфоновского сафари. Пробовал позиционировать через `bottom`, через проценты, `vw`, даже если пишешь пикселы, к примеру `320px`, то будет везде `320px` а в этом браузере оно съезджает или вверх или вниз. Огромное спасибо тому, кто поможет :)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Возможно дело в том, что ты не учитываешь [safe area](https://css-live.ru/articles/ponimanie-vyuporta-webview-v-ios-11.html).
Также стоит проверить наличия метатега viewport.